# Why does it fail to read the ListView?

Tags: android, string, sqlite, listview

When I click on a ListView item then I got following message:
How can I read out the item and get the items name to a string?

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@40706330

```
public void onListItemClick(
ListView parent, View v,
int position, long id)
{   
    Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    String keyword = o.toString();

    Toast.makeText(this, keyword, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

This way I can read the position from the item:

```
    public void onListItemClick(
ListView parent, View v,
int position, long id)
{   
    open_database_rw();

    Object itemId = this.getListAdapter().getItemId(position);
    String item = itemId.toString();

    Toast.makeText(this, item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Now I like to read out the selected data into a toast. I tried it this way but it didn't work:

```
public void onListItemClick(
ListView parent, View v,
int position, long id)
{   
    open_database_rw();

    Cursor cursor = db.query("tbl_homework", new String[] {"hw"}, 
            "_id = 1", null, null, null, null);

    int column = cursor.getColumnIndex("hw");
    String item = cursor.getString(column);

    Toast.makeText(this, item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Errormessage: 
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1

Problem has been solved! I had to move the cursor to first
cursor.moveToFirst();

Full working code:

```
public void onListItemClick(
ListView parent, View v,
int position, long id)
{   
    open_database_rw();

    Object itemId = this.getListAdapter().getItemId(position);
    String item = itemId.toString();

    Cursor cursor = db.query("tbl_homework", new String[] {"hw"}, 
            "_id =" + item, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int column = cursor.getColumnIndex("hw");
    String hw = cursor.getString(column);
    Toast.makeText(this, hw, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: how are you setting your list adapter? add that code too

Comment: I don't have one^^ How can I read out those data without list adapter?

Answer (score 2):

if you don't know what you have inserted in your ListView, then how can you specify which Column to read?

anyhow, you may try your luck by doing this:

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v,int position, long id)
{   
    Cursor c = (Cursor) this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);

    // if 0 doesn't work then try 1, 2, 3
    // and so on (depending on your columns length)
    String keyword = c.getString(0);

    Toast.makeText(this, keyword, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: That worked fine to me... Thanks! Next problem: I can't do a select query to my database...

Comment: you need to iterate your desired column through cursor

Comment: I researched an hour and read about 10 posts on how to do this until I came across your post. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Calling `getItem()` returns the "item" associated with a given position in the `Adapter`. In the case of a `CursorAdapter`, `getItem()` returns the `Cursor`, set to the proper position. If you wish to get data out of the `Cursor`, call `getString()`, `getInt()`, or any of the other column getters [on the `Cursor` interface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html).

Comment: Thanks for that help! Now I have a new problem (Edit on my question)

Comment: @MarcoSeiz: In my answer, I wrote: "If you wish to get data out of the Cursor, call getString(), getInt(), or any of the other column getters on the Cursor interface." You did not do this.

Comment: I tried it this way:Cursor cursor = db.query("tbl_homework", new String[] {"hw"}, "_id = 1", null, null, null, null);
     
     String item = cursor.getString(1);
     
        Toast.makeText(this, item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Still not working...
Errormessage : Index -1 requested, with a size of 1

Comment: @MarcoSeiz: You need to have the `Cursor` positioned on a valid row. You do not. Use `moveToPosition()`, `moveToFirst()`, or something else to position the `Cursor` on a row.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will solve the problem:

```
public void onListItemClick(
ListView parent, View v,
int position, long id)
{   
    open_database_rw();

    Object itemId = this.getListAdapter().getItemId(position);
    String item = itemId.toString();

    Cursor cursor = db.query("tbl_homework", new String[] {"hw"}, 
            "_id =" + item, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int column = cursor.getColumnIndex("hw");
    String hw = cursor.getString(column);
    Toast.makeText(this, hw, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

It's necessary to move the cursor to first.